# WebClient Unicode - Which UTF8?

Tags: c#, .net, unicode, utf-8, webclient

When I create a WebClient to consume some RESTful xml, I can specify the unicode encoding 2 ways:

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient ();
wc.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
wc.Encoding = UTF8Encoding.UTF8;
```

Which is correct/better ?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

They're identical.

`UTF8Encoding` inherits `Encoding`.
Therefore, you can access all of the static members declared by `Encoding` through the `UTF8Encoding` qualifier.

In fact, you can even write `ASCIIEncoding.UTF8`, and it will still work.

It will compile to identical IL, even in debug mode.

---

I would recommend using `Encoding.UTF8`, as it shows what's going on more clearly.

Comment: My general rule of thumb is to always access a static member from the the type it is was declared on, and not any of it's inheritors. In this case, Encoding.

Comment: @vcsjones: Yes.  That's more or less what I meant at the end.