# Why is it useful to access static members "through" inherited types?

Tags: c#, inheritance, static, language-design

I'm glad C# doesn't let you access static members 'as though' they were instance members. This avoids a common bug in Java:

```
Thread t = new Thread(..);
t.sleep(..); //Probably doesn't do what the programmer intended.
```

On the other hand, it *does* let you access static members 'through' derived types. Other than operators (where it saves you from writing casts), I can't think of any cases where this is actually helpful. In fact, it actively encourages mistakes such as:

```
// Nasty surprises ahead - won't throw; does something unintended:
// Creates a HttpWebRequest instead.
var ftpRequest = FtpWebRequest.Create(@"http://www.stackoverflow.com");

// Something seriously wrong here.
var areRefEqual = Dictionary<string, int>.ReferenceEquals(dict1, dict2);
```

I personally keep committing similar errors over and over when I am searching my way through unfamiliar APIs (I remember starting off with expression trees; I hit `BinaryExpression.` in the editor and was wondering why on earth IntelliSense was offering me `MakeUnary` as an option).

In my (shortsighted) opinion, this feature:

1. Doesn't reduce verbosity; the programmer has to specify a type-name one way or another (excluding operators and cases when one is accessing inherited static members of the current type).
2. Encourages bugs/ misleading code such as the one above.
3. May suggest to the programmer that static methods in C# exhibit some sort of 'polymorphism', when they don't.
4. (Minor) Introduces 'silent', possibly unintended rebinding possibilities on recompilation.

(IMO, operators are a special case that warrant their own discussion.)

Given that C# is normally a "pit of success" language, why does this feature exist? I can't see its benefits (other than 'discoverability', which could always be solved in the IDE), but I see lots of problems.

Comment: Or, worse, `UTF8Encoding.ASCII`.

Comment: I agree that it can be slightly misleading, but it is consistent with the principle that *inherited members are treated as members of the derived type*. Note that we explicitly do *not* allow this pattern on constrained type parameters because then it really is potentially quite misleading. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/06/14/calling-static-methods-on-type-parameters-is-illegal-part-one.aspx
 for details.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd agree this is a misfeature. I don't know how often someone on Stack Overflow has posted code of:

```
ASCIIEncoding.ASCII
```

etc... which, while harmless in terms of *execution* is misleading in terms of reading the code.

Obviously it's too late to remove this "feature" now, although I guess the C# team could introduce a super-verbose warning mode for this and other style issues.

Maybe C#'s successor will improve things...

Comment: Actually, I've only seen that [once](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4252426/webclient-unicode-which-utf8) on SO.

Comment: StyleCop could try to catch these.

Comment: Like @SLaks said, `UTF8Encoding.ASCII` is even worse

Comment: ReSharper definitely warns about this...."Access to a static member of a type via a derived type". Yey!

Comment: @digEmAll: Yes, but fortunately I haven't seen that as often :)

Comment: @Jon: yes, fortunately people tend to not hurt themselves :)

Comment: @Jon Skeet: So in order to access a static member, you'd have to know the entire inheritance hierarchy? What about if class `B` defines a static method `S()` and class `D` derives from `B`.  Should `D` have to say `B.S()`? Somehow that feels wrong, but I don't (yet?) have a strong argument in defense of the current behavior.

Comment: @Jim: No, I'd allow it to work for access to ancestors of the "current" class - but where you currently specify a type name, it would have to be the right one.

Comment: @Jon: So there's really no benefit to this at all, then? Pure misfeature all the way?

Answer (score 2):

This is useful in WinForms.

In any control or form, you can write `MousePosition`, `MouseButtons`, or `ModifierKeys` to use the `static` members inherited from `Control`.

It's still debatable whether it was a good decision.

Comment: You could still have access to "inherited" static members through the implicit context of writing a class, but not be able to access them *when specifying a type name* other than the right one.

Comment: True.  I'm not sure whether I can think of any uses for that.

Comment: I agree with Jon, these two things are somewhat orthogonal. The silent rebinding issue is still there though, although that's minor and unlikely to crop up in WinForms.

Comment: @Ani: There are a lot of things where different kinds of inheritance behaviors could logically be orthogonal, but are constrained by language or framework design.  For example, there's no particular reason why an unsealed class `Foo` shouldn't be able to let outside code to use a constructor to construct new `Foo` instances without allowing that same constructor to be used to construct `DerivedFoo` instances, or why `Foo` shouldn't be able to specify an implementation for method `Bar()` but require that any derived classes must supply their own alternate implementation.

Comment: @Ani: I don't think the "problem" here is so much the fact that static members in particular are inherited, so much as that there's no standard means by which any kind of class member can be made public but not inheritable.