# Preventing inheritance of static member

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, static, language-design

Base:

```
public abstract class systemClient : IDisposable
{
    public static List<systemClient> Collection = new List<systemClient>();
    [...]
}
```

derived class

```
public class station : systemClient
{
    [...]
}
```

In this setup I can access `station.Collection`.

Question is:
**Is there a way to hide** `station.Collection` **?**

Comment: It would help if you'd show a *real* example. In your example `example` is implicitly private anyway... It would also help if your example followed .NET naming conventions..

Comment: **Static** members are not inherited. It is compiler that allows you to call the static field through the inheriting class, but technically it is incorrect.

Comment: @Maarten judging from (amongst other things) this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281775/c-sharp-static-member-inheritance-why-does-this-exist-at-all  it seems this is intended behavioud. That's also backed by the fact that it compiles and runs just fine.

Comment: @Mark The answers to your referred question do not make it explicit IMHO. Also, IMHO, it is a compiler trick, and not inheritance, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/2288663/261050. Also, other questions, such as this one, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945439/why-is-it-useful-to-access-static-members-through-inherited-types, are not that positive about the 'feature'.

Comment: @Maarten more like syntactic saccharin to me. I find that more confusing that useful tbh.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. By creating `inhClass` as a subclass of `baseClass` `inhClass` **must** provide everything that `baseClass` provides. Otherwise `baseClass x = new inhClass()` would be invalid.

In this specific case though you have made the method static, that means that it doesn't actually have its own copy of the method. `inhClass` is just accessing the static one within `baseClass`.

Comment: I thought that was a different story for `static` members, but if I carefully think about it, that wouldn't make sense.

Comment: Well, it is slightly different... but I'm more of a Java expert than a dot net one so I don't know enough of the specifics on the dot net side to go into them.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Tim B answer. You can't simply "ignore" some methods or properties of a class which you inherits. But, what you can do is implementing an [interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87d83y5b.aspx), which may do the work you want. For further reading, take a look [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80739/how-to-implement-only-a-part-of-an-interface).